# How can I specify the global post when using custom links with add_rewrite_rule in WordPress, despite having a city title at the end of the link?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress
the site uses links of cities that should be added to the end of almost every link, using add_rewrite_rule, I created custom links, but because of the city at the end, the generated global post is always the city that is substituted at the end, and not the post or page to which the link should enter.

How to designate a global post using a link? Or should I ignore the city at the end of the link? I've been racking my head for a few days, I've tried everything I knew and could Google.